# react-router: How does a <Link /> render is triggered when route change?

Tags: react-router, react-router-redux

Ok so I made an early issue on the `react-router` github issue tracker about my `<Link />` not updating. 
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/3522

After trying to reproduce in a simple example, I realize it doesn't seem to be a bug with `react-router`. My next potential guilty are either my complicated set-up or just the mix with `react-router` & `react-router-redux`.

To continue my investigation, I was looking for help to understand how the Link render method is triggered when the route change since the props don't seem to change. (I'm only looking for the activeStyle to adapt properly)

I actually found a workaround by adding

```
Link.componentDidMount = () => {
  this.context.router.listen(() => this.setState({}))
}
```

but I think it would be better to have a clean fix :P

Comment: Why does it need to re-render? Does something change that has to be re-drawn? I don't fully understand.

Comment: Hi Chris ! Thanks for the answer :) The that I want to be redrawn is the activeStyle but the render method is not a pure method. The `if (isActive)` kinda test deciding weather or not adding the `activeStyle` is not coming from props but from `this.context.router.isActive(location)`. So I don't understand how it's supposed to be trigger.